# Azure Dataflow Source- Not able to establish API connection

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a data flow in Azure data factory but when I attempt to call the API connection, it throws me an error. This API connection was working fine when I used in copy activity but it does not work in data flow.

Here is the link to [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eHqm.jpg)

Please tell me what wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same dataset for both copy data activity and dataflow source? If yes, Can you please provide additional information

Comment: Can you tell me what additional details you need?
Below are steps I have done during this process: 1. Click on Data flow, add source -> add data set using the same api connection as shown in the above screenshot.
2. Check data flow debug option -> Integrationruntime -> Autointegrationruntime selected
3. Tested the data set connection in source 
This gives me error
Please let me know what additional information you might need.